# Matlab solve command gives four equations instead of 2 real solutions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve the following equation:`x^4 - 3*x^3 + x^2 - 1` by doing: `solve(x^4 - 3*x^3 + x^2 - 1 == 0)` I am expecting either two real solutions or four solutions where two of them are real and two solutions are imaginary: (all are estimates) -0.57, 2.68, 0.45 + 0.67i, 0.45 - 0.67i. Instead I get the following

```
ans =
root(z^4 - 3*z^3 + z^2 - 1, z, 1)
root(z^4 - 3*z^3 + z^2 - 1, z, 2)
root(z^4 - 3*z^3 + z^2 - 1, z, 3)
root(z^4 - 3*z^3 + z^2 - 1, z, 4)
```

Why do I get roots of a variable z, and what does this format of "root(eqation, z, num)" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by doing the following

```
syms x
eqn = x^4 - 3*x^3 + x^2 - 1 == 0;

solved = vpa(solve(eqn, x, 'MaxDegree', 4));
```

The solutions are in equation form that are really long instead of decimal without the `vpa` function. I do not get the solutions in any useful form when I omit `'MaxDegree', 4`, so that is also essential for getting solutions to the equation. Adding `'Real', true` made it so that the equation only has real solutions, if somebody who stumbles onto the same problem finds that relevant!

Comment: that is extremelly inefficient. Why don't just use the [roots built-in function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html)?

Comment: @Thales I know but this is what my professor specified to use.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the symbolic toolbox, something I highly discourage to do. If you have a numerical problem, use a numerical algorithm to get what you want.

By typing `solve(x^4 - 3*x^3 + x^2 - 1 == 0)`, MATLAB will simply state that the roots for this equation are the roots to the given polynomial, and it will express this roots using the [root function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.root.html). Take a look on the documentation of the function to understand how it works and what does it do. Notice that you can get find explicitly the roots, setting the maximum degree of the polynomial when calling the solve function. Notice, also, that not every polinomial will have a closed form solution.

If you are working with polynomials - and polynomials only - you will be much better off if you use MATLAB's extensive library on polynomials. Check the documentation on how to create polynomials [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/create-and-evaluate-polynomials.html) and how to get the roots of the polynomial [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/roots-of-polynomials.html). Essentially, you define a polynomial saving in an array its coefficients and use the [roots](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html) to get the (numerical) roots.

```
% polynomial p(x)=x^4 - 3*x^3 + x^2 - 1
p = [1 -3 1 0 -1]; % coefficients
roots(p) % roots of polynomial
```

Comment: I have looked at the documentation for the function "solve". I have copied their exact first example with "syms a b c x" and that example works. However when I try to do it for my own function, it does not work. Basically it does not work with numbers, only symbols.

Comment: I managed to get 4 solutions by doing solve(eqn, x, 'MaxDegree', 4). However the solutions are extremely long and in the form of an equation instead of a number. Any solutions?

Comment: why do you want to solve it with the `solve` function? Is it a polynomial? Just use the `roots` function, it is much better. The analytical solution for a polynomial of degree 4 is extremely long, as you can check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots).